# SearchFieldError Django and Haystack

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm trying to setup haystack but I have some errors from the beginning.
I have the following error when trying to open search url:

```
All 'SearchIndex' classes must use the same 'text' fieldname for the 'document=True' field. Offending index is '<subtitrari.search_indexes.PictureIndex object at 0x7f3a6819be20>'.
```

Any clue of how to make it working?

Thank you.

Here is my code:

## models.py

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    imdb_id = models.CharField(max_length=9, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tv_show = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genre = TaggableManager(verbose_name=u'Genres')
    poster = models.ImageField(upload_to=poster_path, blank=True, null=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(max_length=3, null=True, blank=True)
    votes = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True, blank=True)
    plot = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    trailer = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.title

     def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.title
```

## search_indexes.py

```
import datetime

from haystack import indexes

from subtitrari.models import Picture

class PictureIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    title = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    uploader = indexes.CharField(model_attr='uploader')
    created_at = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='created_at')

    def get_model(self):
        return Picture

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.filter(created_at__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the tutorial, don't change the document field name into `title`, leave it as `text`.